# Singleton gets destroyed

Tags: android, service, android-activity, singleton

I have an activity that starts a service. There is also a singleton `Data` involved. When I close the activity by going to the homescreen, the `Data` singleton gets destroyed after a while, but, as it should, the service keeps running. Therefore some fields of `Data` become `null` again, and the service encounters nullpointers.

How can I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know, `Activity` instances get launched inside their own classloader, for security. Any singleton attached to a class that gets loaded as a result of loading your `Activity` is tied to that classloader, which is in turn tied to the activity lifecycle.

That is, I don't think you can guarantee that this won't happen, and therefore, shouldn't rely on it.

You need to serialize any persistent state and then unserialize it when the `Activity` starts.

Comment: Any ideas on the following situation then? The service periodically retrieves some data, and stores it in the 'Data' instance. The activity, when active, shows this data in its UI.

Comment: Singletons are a bit tricky in Android for this very reason, so I would avoid them. Instead, you want to serialize your data in `onPause()` and restore it `onResume()` and then have any dependent classes access that managed instance of `Data` in your activity.

Answer (score 1):

One way we accomplish this is to store a reference to your object in your subclass of the `Application` you create. This is a simple workaround that works in most cases without needing to create a `Service` or to have to serialise the state all the time.